# Constraining Folium Map navigation within a bounded area

Tags: python, leaflet, zooming, folium

I aim to generate a folium map centered on a specific location while imposing limitations on user movement outside a defined zone.

First, we can set a minimum zoom level to prevent excessive zooming out.

Here's a code snippet utilizing Python libraries like `geopandas` and `folium` to achieve this:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Define the coordinates of the central location
point_coordinates = (2.3546, 48.8517)
point = Point(point_coordinates)

# Create a folium map centered on the specified location with a minimum zoom level
m = folium.Map(location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]], min_zoom=9)

# Add a marker to the map at the specified location
folium.Marker(
    location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]],
    icon=folium.Icon(color='blue'),
    popup="Point of Interest"
).add_to(m)

# Display the map
m
```

Now, my inquiry pertains to the process of defining a bounding box (bbox) that restricts user movement to remain within a designated rectangle. How might I go about achieving this objective?